# Put numbers in a txt file

Tags: python, math

I am trying to put the output of these numbers into a file but I am failing a bit.
This is my code so far :

```
import os
import sys

with open('somefile.txt', 'rt') as f:
   print('Hello World!')
os.system("pause")

num = int(input("Display multiplication table of? "))

for i in range(1,1000001):
   print(num*i, file=f)

os.system("pause")
```

The programm says the = at file=f has a syntax error. Any1 know why?

Comment: yes. There is no `f` at that point. Think about what `with` does.

Comment: also, the fact that is a `syntax error` seems to suggest you are using python 2. If so, you need to do a `__future__` import since printing to a file with `print` is not directly available in python 2

Comment: I am using python 3.5 Maybe I need an update?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you did wrong:

`- Didn't have f defined when you wrote to the file
 - Didn't have the file opened as a write - you had it open as a read`

After fixing them, the code executed perfectly!

```
import os
import sys 
f = open('somefile.txt', 'wt') # CHANGED LINE
print('Hello World!')
os.system("pause")
num = int(input("Display multiplication table of? "))
for i in range(1,1000001):
   print(num*i, file=f)
os.system("pause")
```

Comment: Sorry but I am still getting the error that the = gives a syntax error between file and f...

Comment: 2.7, I installed both, I see where my problem is now. I'm gonna uninstall 2.7 right away

Comment: Oh yeah, that'll be your problem.